# Float в css

Tags: float, css

http://jsfiddle.net/g9gxc3so/

Как сделать, чтобы синие прямоугольники подогнались сами нормально под чёрную полосу? Без всяких там прописаний разных width у каждого элемента и т.д?

Пример на изображении:

[image]

Comment: через display: table-cell или все-таки width в процентах

Comment: @Etki, можете показать на моём примере jsfiddle display: table-cell? http://jsfiddle.net/g9gxc3so/

Comment: @ModaL http://jsfiddle.net/g9gxc3so/3/

Comment: @Etki, получилось, отлично. Превратите в ответ комментарий, отмечу его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажи прямоугольникам class и назначай ширину сразу для всех в одном месте, внутри стилей.